# Zend Twitter Feed how to pull users profile image along with post

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, twitter

Currently in my view I can pull each post (I am currently messing with getting the date aswell, if anyone knows how to format that quickly please do tell :D)

my view currently looks like this:

```
<?php




                            // Show tweet text
                           foreach ($this->twitterfeed as $post) {

                             echo '<p><time> '.$post->created_at . '</time> ';
                             echo $post->text . ' ';
                                echo '</p><br/>';
                            }
                            ?>
```

Obviously the $post->text is pulling the text portion of the post however how do pull the users profile image?

Answer (score 0):

`$post->profile_image_url` should give you the avatar URL, and you should be able to format the `created_at` by first running it through `strtotime()` to give you a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: profile_image_url is giving the error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$profile_image_url" and thanks for the strtotime()!

Comment: Strange, that's what my code uses. I'd suggest temporarily adding `var_dump($post)` to see what data you have in there